# Ethers.js - Restore signature generation

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I'm trying to understand how a smart contract handle transaction signatures with the help of checks they do in their code

Checks they do in smart contract transactions method :

```
// signHeader = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32"
// signerAddress = 0x95d0bdBcc0A42DF16A31d18cb65671c48E2C942E;
require(ecrecover(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(signHeader, proposedHash)), v, r, s) == signerAddress, "Invalid Sign");
require(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(payAmount, merchantId, nonce, "nsp_noonce")) == proposedHash, "Havoc");
```

I succeeded to reproduce `proposedHash` with the help of one of their transaction

Here's the snippet I'm using to reproduce the signature, I'm only failing to reproduce v,r,s (so the splitted signature)

```
const toSign = ethers.solidityPackedKeccak256(
    ["uint256", "uint256", "uint256", "string"],
    [/* payAmount */239086500, /* merchantId */206, /* nonce */1706609888830, "nsp_noonce"]
);
const toSignExpected = "0x5bc9d5c2d416605ae3a34d3e7cc038ff5d7030d24210fddce3e74dfd6cc57bf1";
console.log("toSign", toSign === toSignExpected);

const msgHash = ethers.solidityPackedKeccak256(
    ["string", "bytes32"],
    ["\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", toSign]
);

const wallet = await contract.getWallet();
let sig = await wallet.signMessage(ethers.getBytes(msgHash));
console.log(sig);

const { v, r, s } = ethers.Signature.from(sig);
const rExpected = "0x5104e9b2111345cf5ff46da4c8571b0f33d8b08a23c3e5d6013bd3ffad3593f1";
const sExpected = "0x39d5b40cf57a79aceac33f929e54411f0d53d352a27e3d3103cf32fe49cb47e6";
const vExpected = "0x1c";

console.log("r", r === rExpected);
console.log("s", s === sExpected);
console.log("v", v === vExpected);
```

Transaction to reproduce: https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x51da675f7f21add4d8702ab8da91894372683b2731622c3a090593d57d5a66b6